# How to assign two separate events to a div tag on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

In my page I am asking users to submit a poll by clicking on the respective options (radio button or check box). Now my options can be images, text, video or audio. Now actual problem is I need my option html div tag to select the radio button/check-box if user clicks anywhere on it, even on video/audio/image thumbnail. But the other requirement is if I click on the video/audio i need to play then using a modal and if user clicks on Image then I have to show the image in zoomed manner. 
Both of these events should happen if user clicks on media as media is inside option html. To show Images I am using lightbox plugin and I am binding lightbox event to image tag as options are loading.

```
        //option html : var eachQ = <div class="optionEntry">......</div> 
         if (media == 'image') { $('.mediaImage', eachQ).lightBox(); }
         if (media == 'audio') { /*play audio*/ }
         if (media == 'video') { /*play audio*/ }

         $('.optionEntry', eachQ).click(function(event) {
              alert("option selected")
             //select the option
          });
```

Now this code works fine for playing audio and videos as I am able to both play and select the option if I click on audio/video thumbnail, but if I click on image then I am watching the lightbox plugin image view and the option is not selected. Please let me know if any other info is needed to answer this nad thank you in advance. I am using dynamic html and adding that to optionEntry tag, that is as following;

```
var textType = '<div class="textType"><div class="tickHolder"></div><span class=text></span></div>';
    var imgType = '<div class="imgType"><div class="tickHolder"></div><div class="mediaHolder"><img class="mediaImage"></img></div></div>';
    var videoType = '<div class="videoType"><div class="tickHolder"></div><div class="mediaHolder"><img class="mediaVideo"></img> <div class="playIcon"></div></div></div>';
    var audioType = '<div class="audioType"><div class="tickHolder"></div><div class="mediaHolder"><img class="mediaAudio"></img></div></div>';
```

Comment: Could you also paste the html related to the question, it would help when answering.

Comment: i don't understand... when you click on image's container not show the alert?? how if the event not triggered?

Comment: yeah.... thats the thing i am unable to figure out why this event does not get triggered.... it has no reason not to, unless there is something in plugin that is stopping it to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, wrap the object in a  tag, like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" name="myCheckbox">
<label for="myCheckbox"><img (or whatever)></label>
```

Comment: I am doing that too dynamically as <span class="radioSpan"><input type="radio" class="radioBtns"/><span> and prepending this to that option html

Comment: The difference is that the label's default behavior is to select the input it's pointing to. Try it.

Comment: Alternatively, you need to look in the lightbox's plugin files to see what's interfering with your desired outcome. Or write a plugin of your own, that way you can control the outcome and learn from the experience!